# Javascript - how to access a variable defined in the braces of another variable

Tags: javascript

suppose I have declared a global variable test in some file:

```
var test = {
  function1: function(){
    testV = "ok";
    checkFile();
  }
}
```

How do I access testV in another file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That variable is defined in a scope local to that function. You would need to define that variable first in the global scope, and then reference it inside this function and then inside the second function.

For more information, [see "What is the scope of variables in JavaScript?"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript)

Comment: edited! but I dont know how to reference into the variables inside the function namespaced as function1

Comment: @LeoLi your edit changes the whole concept of your question and makes this answer incorrect although it nicely answered your original question. Don't do that... you can't externally access variables defined in local scopes of a function.

Comment: @LeoLi No problem, I said it because someone else might come with the same question, but won't find the answer because you included the answer in the question. :) Welcome to Stack Overflow!